# Appending the values to the already existing dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary and I wanted to update the value to the already existing key

I have followed some link in stack overflow and it didnt solve my problem.You can see what I did in the below part. I have tried with append and set default

```
each_dict.setdefault('st',[]).append(5)
```

I got the idea of append and set default from other links of stack overflow ,but that didnt work

```
my_dict = [{'id':1,'name':'aa','st':1,'et':2},{'id':2,'name':'bb','st':3,'et':6}
for each_dict in my_dict:
      each_dict['st'].append(3)
```

My expected result is:

```
my_dict = [{'id':1,'name':'aa','st':1,3,6,7'et':2,8,9,10},{'id':2,'name':'bb','st':3,9,'et':6,10}
```

But error message is:

> int object has no attribute append

Comment: The `setdefault` approach works only if there is either no `st` key or if the key is a list already. You need to ensure the value at key `st` is a list before appending anything to it.

Comment: each_dict['st'] is 1 in the first dict and 3 in the other, in other words they are _numbers_. You can't append to a number.

Comment: Your expected result (`'st': 1,3,6,7'et':2,8,9,10`) is not valid Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of solutions:

```
my_dict = [{'id':1,'name':'aa','st':1,'et':2},{'id':2,'name':'bb','st':3,'et':6}]
for each_dict in my_dict:
    if type(each_dict['st']) == list:
        each_dict['st'].append(3)
    else:
        each_dict['st'] = [each_dict['st'], 3]

print (my_dict)
```

output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'aa', 'st': [1, 3], 'et': 2}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'bb', 'st': [3, 3], 'et': 6}]
```

Comment: you're welcome. I'm glad I helped :) 
generally don't forget to upvote or accept an answer :)